# Restructuring array for Highcharts use

Tags: php, highcharts

I have multiple arrays that follow the format of the example below, and I would like to know how I can programmatically restructure the arrays for use with Highcharts (specifically Highstock). I'd like to be able to compare the data of each array as is shown in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/compare/).[Date] should be the X-axis and [Close] should be the Y-axis for a given point of data.

Array Example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Date] => 2013-03-06
            [Open] => 3.79
            [High] => 3.64
            [Low] => 3.48
            [Close] => 3.52
            [Volume] => 22184500
            [Adj Close] => 3.72
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Date] => 2013-03-05
            [Open] => 3.63
            [High] => 3.05
            [Low] => 3.28
            [Close] => 3.54
            [Volume] => 32987900
            [Adj Close] => 3.14
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Date] => 2013-03-04
            [Open] => 3.50
            [High] => 3.67
            [Low] => 3.50
            [Close] => 3.64
            [Volume] => 47933200
            [Adj Close] => 3.84
        )
)
```

Please let me know if you need more information or have any questions.

Thanks

Comment: What is your desired output ?

Comment: Whatever is easiest for Highcharts to consume. I assume the only values I'll need are [Date] and [Close] values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do something like this:

```
   $i = 0;
    foreach($your_array as $val){
       $res[$i][]   = strtotime($val['Date']) * 1000; //sets the date as a javascript timestamp
       $res[$i][]   = (float)$val['Close']; //make sure it is formatted as a number not a string
       $i++;
    }
    json_encode($res);
```

You should have json that you can pass as your data object in the chart.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what actually are you looking for,

Try this :

```
$res              = array();
foreach($your_array as $key=>$val){
   $res[$key]['Date']   = $val['Date'];
   $res[$key]['Close']  = $val['Close'];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```

Comment: This is good for getting rid of irrelevant data, but it only returns one loop through `$your_array`. I'd like it to get through as many loops as there are items in the array.